# Optional match after comma in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, optional-parameters

I tried so hard and got so far but in the end it doesn't work!!

What I would like to do achieve is the following:
I've got a preg_replace_callback function where I want to address my "dictionary" function.

I use my own "dictionary" tag:

```
<[general,username]>
<[general,username,1]>
```

this should call my function "dictionary". The function with it's ararguments is: `dictionary($search,$section,$upper=null)`

```
$search = filename
$section = array key
$upper = (int) 1 to 3
```

my callback function calls the function with the values from the "dictionary" tags.

```
for <[general,username]> I need
- $search = general
- $section = username
- $upper = null

but for <[general,username,1]> I want
- $search = general
- $section = username
- $upper = 1
```

I want my regular expression to always match 2 arguments (search and section) but have a third optional argument.

My regex:

```
/\<\[([^\[]+)\,([^\[]+)(\,[0-2])?\]\>/
```

but this doesn't work correctly. I get the following results:

for <[general,username]> I get

```
[0] => <[general,username]>
[1] => general
[2] => username
```

for <[general,username,1]> I get

```
[0] => <[general,username,1]>
[1] => general,username
[2] => 1
```

but I would like

```
[0] => <[general,username,1]>
[1] => general
[2] => username
[3] => 1
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
/\<\[([^\,]+)\,([^\,]+)(?:\,(\d+))?\]\>/
```

```
 - Item[0] => whole matching text
 - Item[1] => general
 - Item[2] => username
 - Item[3] => upper (if match)
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex is greedy by default, so the first group is matching the first comma as well.  Try this instead:

```
/\<\[([^\[,]+)\,([^\[,]+)(?:\,([0-2]))?\]\>/
```

Comment: That expression would group the number but also a comma, **(\,[0-2])?**, so the result for upper is wrong = ",<number>"

Comment: Oops, I should've looked more closely at that part.  I'll edit that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the comma from the range of the second group....

Or, assuming the first 2 terms are alphanumeric only:

```
\<\[(\w+)\,(\w+)\,?(\d+)?\]\>
```